# Remove specific missing values in r

Tags: r

my data set has missing values marked as 'XXX'

I have tried na.omit(mydata)

```r
df <- data.frame(X=factor(c(0.2, "XXX", 0.4, 0.1)), Y=factor(c(0.8, 1, 0.9, "XXX")))
```

here X and Y are factors. I found that the missing data is encoded as "XXX" by checking the levels of the factor.

I want to remove row "2" and row "4". can someone help, I have been trying for a while now.

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to filter data frame with conditions of two columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084462/how-to-filter-data-frame-with-conditions-of-two-columns)

Comment: If any answers have solved your question, please mark the preferable one as "accepted" by clicking the check mark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can also filter for complete cases like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
df %>% replace(.=="XXX", NA_character_) %>% filter(complete.cases(.))
```

The output is:

```
> df %>% replace(.=="XXX", NA_character_) %>% filter(complete.cases(.))
    X   Y
1 0.2 0.8  
2 0.4 0.9
```

Comment: `library(magrittr)` is not necessary.

Comment: There are pipes in the example.

Comment: `dplyr` has already loaded the pipe function. You can try to restart your R session, `library(dplyr)` and run your code again, it works without the need of `magrittr`.

Answer (score 1):

Two `base R` solutions:

```
df <- subset(df, X != "XXX" & Y != "XXX")
```

or

```
df <- df[df$X != "XXX" & df$Y != "XXX",]
```

`dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% filter(X != "XXX" & Y != "XXX")
```

Gives us:

```
    X   Y
1 0.2 0.8
3 0.4 0.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `tidyverse`:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), str_replace, "XXX", NA_character_)) %>%
  drop_na()

#     X   Y
# 1 0.2 0.8
# 2 0.4 0.9
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert `"XXX"` to `NA`. Just filter `"XXX"` directly.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(across(everything(), ~ . != "XXX"))

#     X   Y
# 1 0.2 0.8
# 2 0.4 0.9
```

The corresponding version using `filter_all()`.

```
df %>% filter_all(all_vars(. != "XXX"))
```

---

A base R solution.

```
df[rowSums(df == "XXX") == 0, ]
```