# Filter dataframe based on the values of two variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I am trying to create a dataframe where I transform and select variables based on the value rows take in two different columns. Let me explain.

This is what my data frame currently looks like:

`ONSConstID` is an id of each constituency. Each row is a different constituency.

All columns ending in `vote15` are vote counts for each party in a constituency.

All columns ending in `sex15` are the candidates' gender for each party.

The other columns aren't really relevant for what I am trying to do.

```
    dput(c[1:40,])
structure(list(ONSConstID = structure(c("W07000049", "W07000058", 
"S14000001", "S14000002", "S14000058", "S14000003", "E14000530", 
"E14000531", "E14000532", "W07000043", "E14000533", "S14000004", 
"W07000057", "S14000005", "E14000534", "E14000535", "E14000536", 
"E14000537", "E14000538", "S14000006", "S14000010", "S14000048", 
"E14000539", "S14000007", "E14000540", "E14000541", "E14000542", 
"E14000543", "E14000544", "E14000933", "E14000545", "E14000546", 
"E14000547", "E14000548", "E14000549", "E14000550", "E14000551", 
"E14000552", "E14000813", "E14000841"), label = "ONS Constituency ID", format.stata = "%9s"), 
    ConPPCsex19 = structure(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0), label = "Conservative 2019 candidate sex", format.stata = "%10.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), LabPPCsex19 = structure(c(0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), label = "Labour 2019 candidate sex", format.stata = "%10.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), LDPPCsex19 = structure(c(1, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, NA, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, 1, 0, 1, 0), label = " 2019 candidate sex", format.stata = "%10.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), SNPPPCsex19 = structure(c(NA, NA, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 0, 1, 1, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), label = "Scottish National Party (SNP) 2019 candidate sex", format.stata = "%10.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), PCPPCsex19 = structure(c(0, 1, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), label = " 2019 candidate sex", format.stata = "%10.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), UKIPPPCsex19 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), label = "United Kingdom Independence Party (UKIP) 2019 candidate sex", format.stata = "%10.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), GreenPPCsex19 = structure(c(1, 
    NA, 0, NA, NA, 1, 1, 0, 1, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, NA, NA, 0, 0, NA, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1), label = "Green 2019 candidate sex", format.stata = "%10.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), BrexitPPCsex19 = structure(c(1, 
    NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 
    0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA), label = "Brexit 2019 candidate sex", format.stata = "%10.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), ConPPCsex17 = structure(c(1, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), label = "Conservative 2017 candidate sex", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), LabPPCsex17 = structure(c(0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), label = "Labour 2017 candidate sex", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), LDPPCsex17 = structure(c(0, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), label = "Liberal Democrat 2017 candidate sex", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), SNPPPCsex17 = structure(c(NA, NA, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), label = "SNP 2017 candidate sex", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), PCPPCsex17 = structure(c(0, 0, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), label = "Plaid Cymru 2017 candidate sex", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), UKIPPPCsex17 = structure(c(1, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 
    0, NA, NA, NA, 0), label = "UKIP 2017 candidate sex", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), GreenPPCsex17 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 1, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), label = "Green Party 2017 candidate sex", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), ConPPCsex15 = structure(c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), label = "Conservative 2015 candidate sex", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), LabPPCsex15 = structure(c(0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), label = "Labour 2015 candidate sex", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), LDPPCsex15 = structure(c(1, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), label = "Liberal Democrat 2015 candidate sex", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), SNPPPCsex15 = structure(c(NA, NA, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), label = "SNP 2015 candidate sex", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), PCPPCsex15 = structure(c(0, 0, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), label = "Plaid Cymru 2015 candidate sex", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), UKIPPPCsex15 = structure(c(0, 0, 
    NA, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 
    1, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), label = "UKIP 2015 candidate sex", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), GreenPPCsex15 = structure(c(0, 
    1, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 0, 
    NA, 1, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0), label = "Green Party 2015 candidate sex", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(Male = 0, 
    Female = 1, `Non-binary` = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), ConVote15 = structure(c(3742, 12513, 
    5304, 11087, 15916, 3389, 23369, 20558, 26771, 13197, 20106, 
    12900, 3521, 7733, 34331, 10628, 30094, 8610, 28083, 10355, 
    8803, 7968, 30749, 13148, 7019, 5485, 5622, 17525, 22668, 
    19788, 25769, 15122, 17833, 15769, 26730, 33621, 27955, 19625, 
    32544, 34891), label = "2015 Conservative number of votes", format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    LabVote15 = structure(c(15416, 8514, 11397, 12991, 2487, 
    15108, 8468, 8835, 13481, 16540, 15901, 3919, 8122, 5394, 
    6324, 19448, 10580, 19366, 8391, 14227, 13410, 15068, 12354, 
    2647, 24826, 20376, 21079, 18320, 10186, 11493, 14706, 23965, 
    6216, 21826, 18792, 6074, 9484, 18528, 9217, 9247), label = "2015 Labour number of votes", format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    LDVote15 = structure(c(1397, 1391, 2050, 2252, 11812, 678, 
    4076, 1330, 4235, 1733, 1360, 1216, 718, 14486, 4062, 7030, 
    3433, 943, 5885, 855, 917, 896, 3440, 2347, 562, 770, 1217, 
    1169, 1636, 1356, 3919, 1331, 14000, 2396, 2241, 3927, 3378, 
    1958, 4193, 3418), label = "2015 Liberal Democrat number of votes", format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    SNPVote15 = structure(c(NA, NA, 24793, 20221, 22949, 23887, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 24130, NA, 22959, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    25492, 26999, 28641, NA, 27487, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), label = "2015 Scottish National Party (SNP) number of votes", format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    PCVote15 = structure(c(3663, 3536, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1608, NA, NA, 11790, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), label = "2015 Plaid Cymru number of votes", format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    UKIPVote15 = structure(c(4971, 3467, NA, 897, 1006, 1088, 
    8253, 7751, 4047, 7260, 7263, 1355, 2277, 1311, 8154, 10150, 
    10798, 8468, 10925, 1280, NA, 1296, 8050, NA, 9554, 7941, 
    9045, 5070, 8538, 12097, 8290, 7865, 2922, 9080, 1586, 7310, 
    6108, 4434, 8966, 8579), label = "2015 United Kingdom Independence Party (UKIP) number of votes", format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    GreenVote15 = structure(c(711, 727, NA, 964, 885, NA, 2025, 
    826, 1983, 976, 1087, 965, NA, NA, 3606, NA, 2467, 1531, 
    2135, NA, 645, NA, 2686, NA, 897, 938, NA, 1061, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1006, 5634, 1232, 1682, 2231, 1878, 1412, 2462, 2537), label = "2015 Green Party number of votes", format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    BNPVote15 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), label = "2015 British National Party (BNP) number of votes", format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    Winner15 = structure(c(2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 
    5, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
    2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), label = "2015 Winning party", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c(Conservative = 1, 
    Labour = 2, `Liberal Democrat` = 3, `Scottish National Party` = 4, 
    `Plaid Cymru` = 5, UKIP = 6, Green = 7, Speaker. = 9), class = c("haven_labelled", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "double")), Majority15 = structure(c(33.134536687498, 
    13.2645614966167, 30.4898033503278, 14.8915573314659, 12.7418653525618, 
    19.8234204940613, 32.2595310774826, 29.6807352457149, 26.3079755329889, 
    8.09168804763518, 9.1978913751996, 25.2444644262111, 13.6676975816969, 
    16.3309754640248, 46.3498415284098, 18.6040625197747, 33.6331311441121, 
    27.637596998818, 30.9605009112398, 21.5767396425904, 26.7636979556466, 
    25.1963095657985, 31.7111432905806, 31.4251901203182, 35.4824469691689, 
    34.0125820568928, 31.2433470934912, 1.8370883882149, 29.009017384029, 
    16.8688175816463, 20.8436958323913, 17.9411227657287, 8.12644433608243, 
    11.9990491095307, 15.5552507299485, 49.4911874800143, 37.8480831096449, 
    2.38033242199366, 40.1774026868756, 43.7073902372512), label = "2015 Majority", format.stata = "%12.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am trying to get 2 things I am having huge issues with:

1. is to get only the two most voted candidates for each row (`ONSConstID`), meaning those with higher values in the variables ending with `Vote15` (`UKIPVote15`, `LabVote15`, etc.)
2. Is to keep those rows only if one of those two with most votes has `sex15` == 1, and to have the same variables for candidate 1 (most voted) and 2 (second most voted).

Ideally, the final data frame would look something like this. I did it for the 3 first rows:

```
ONSConstID <- c( "W07000058", "S14000001")
votes1 <- c(12513, 20221)
party1 <- c( "Con", "SNP")
sex1 <- c(0, 1)
votes2 <- c(8514, 11397)
party2 <- c("Lab", "Lab" )
sex2 <- c(1, 0)
idealdf <- data.frame(c(ONSConstID, votes1, party1, sex1,
                        votes2, party2, sex2))
idealdf
  ONSConstID votes1 party1 sex1 votes2 party2 sex2
1  W07000058  12513    Con    0   8514    Lab    1
2  S14000001  20221    SNP    1  11397    Lab    0
```

I excluded the 1st row `"W07000049"` because no candidate there had `Sex15` == 1, and then I limited the information for just the 2 most voted candidates.

I have tried many different things with pivoting data back and forth from wide to longer in order to order candidates by vote and select just the 2 higher ones, but I am not able to get to the `idealdf` I am showing here.

Any idea?
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: dput data is too long and isn't working either. Can you revise your Q by posting a small sample of your dataset. Besides, have you seen similar Q in [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084462/how-to-filter-data-frame-with-conditions-of-two-columns), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037199/how-to-filter-dataframe-with-multiple-conditions),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425847/r-subset-data-frame-based-on-multiple-values-for-multiple-variables)?

Comment: > "variables ending with Vote15"

What about `TotalVote15`?

Comment: Can you clarify what "Is to keep those rows only if one of those two with most votes has sex15 == 1, and to have the same variables for candidate 1 (most voted) and 2 (second most voted)." means? It's not possible that party1 == party2, so you must mean something else. Please try to explain what you want further or differently.

Comment: @py_b you're right, sorry. I filter those out. The dput is now updated

Comment: @BrianLang sorry for not being clear. I meant keeping only those rows (ONSConstID) where at least one of the two most voted parties has a value of sex15 == 1. Party 1 is not == party 2, true. What I meant is to have the variables you can see in the "idealdf" for each candidate: votes, party, and sex, i.e. to have a column for the sex, votes and party of each of the most voted candidates for each row/constituency. Let me know if I was any clearer or not. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were probably on the right path with pivoting and spreading and so on, but it's a bit complicated stuff. I commented my code so you see what each line is doing.

```
voting_data %>% 
  ## remove the haven labels
  mutate_all(haven::zap_labels) %>%
  ## turn everything to character so that you can pivot
  mutate_all(as.character)  %>%  
  ## pivot anything with a party name
  pivot_longer(cols = matches("^Lab|^Green|^Con|^LDP|^SNP|^PCP|^UKIP|^Brexit|^PC|^LD|^BNP")) %>%
  ## strip out features of variables
  mutate(date = str_extract(name,pattern = "[0-9]{2}"),
         vartype = str_extract(name, pattern = "sex|Vote"),
         party = str_extract(name, pattern = "^Lab|^Green|^Con|^LDP|^SNP|^PCP|^UKIP|^Brexit|^PC|^LD|^BNP")) %>%
  ## remove the variable "name"
  select(-name) %>%
  ## spread the variable with the "sex" and "vote" values
  spread(vartype, value)  %>%
  ## we only want year 15 and rows with votes!
  filter(date == 15 & !is.na(Vote))  %>%
  ## group by candidate
  group_by(ONSConstID) %>%
  ## arrange by candidate and votes as decreasing
  arrange(ONSConstID, desc(as.numeric(Vote))) %>%
  ## take just the first two rows for each candidate (highest two votes)
  slice(1:2) %>% 
  ## do we only want sex == 1?
  filter(any(sex == 1)) %>%
  ## add place to each row
  mutate(place = 1:n()) %>%
  ## spread to have the format requested.
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(party, sex, Vote), names_from = place)
```

Here are the final results:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 12
# Groups:   ONSConstID [6]
  ONSConstID TotalVote15 RejectedVote15 Winner15 Majority15       date  party_1 party_2 sex_1 sex_2 Vote_1 Vote_2
  <chr>      <chr>       <chr>          <chr>    <chr>            <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
1 E14000531  39497       105            1        29.6807352457149 15    Con     Lab     1     0     20558  8835  
2 E14000535  47409       209            2        18.6040625197747 15    Lab     Con     1     1     19448  10628 
3 E14000537  38918       198            2        27.637596998818  15    Lab     Con     1     1     19366  8610  
4 E14000539  58008       183            1        31.7111432905806 15    Con     Lab     1     0     30749  12354 
5 E14000540  43041       111            2        35.4824469691689 15    Lab     UKIP    1     0     24826  9554  
6 E14000545  53076       219            1        20.8436958323913 15    Con     Lab     1     0     25769  14706
```

Comment: Ahhhh! Damn it, I see what I was doing wrong now. But wouldn't get there alone. Thank you so much for taking the time to help. Super useful